# An abelian Banach algebra with no nonzero morphisms $A \to \mathbb{C}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

We know that if $A$ is a abelian Banach algebra with identity, then the set ‎$\Omega ‎(A)$‎‎‎‎‎ of nonzero homomorphisms $\phi : A \to \mathbb{C}$ isn't empty.

Can you give an example of an abelian Banach algebra without identity $A$ such that $‎\Omega ‎(A) = \varnothing$?

Comment: I do not remember how precisely the example goes, but $\text{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ contains a subalgebra where no characters can exist. If I recall correctly, the sub-Banach algebra of certain uppertriangular fails (checking it on elementary matrices $e_{ij}$ would be enough)

Answer (score 0):

$$\mathcal A:=\mathbb C$$
with
$$a+_{\mathcal A}b:= a+_{\mathbb C}b\qquad a\cdot_{\mathcal A}b:=0\qquad\|a\|_{\mathcal A}:=|a|_{\mathbb C}$$

I'll leave it to you to verify that this is an abelian Banach algebra. For any character $\varphi$ you have $\varphi(a)^2=\varphi(a^2)=0$ for all $a$, so $\varphi(a)=0$.